# $i\left(\log \left(1+e^{-i x}\right)-\log \left(1+e^{i x}\right)\right)=x-2\pi \left\lfloor \frac{x+\pi }{2 \pi }\right\rfloor$

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

Found this relation in my notebook as a simple complex logarithm exercise.

$$i \left(\log \left(1+e^{-i x}\right)-\log \left(1+e^{i x}\right)\right)=x-2\pi  \left\lfloor \frac{x+\pi }{2 \pi }\right\rfloor$$

While can not find any short proof of this now.
I assume this should be something very simple, while hang on proving of this, just putting here as an interesting example and this will save a lot of my time.

Comment: Hint?:use logarithm properties.

Comment: More simple form: $$ i\log e^{-ix}=x- 2\pi  \left\lfloor \frac{x+\pi }{2 \pi }\right\rfloor$$

Comment: @lonestudent yes this simplifies a lot. Actually I would expect to see $i\log e^{-ix}=x- 2\pi  \left\lfloor \frac{x}{2 \pi }\right\rfloor$ instead of $i\log e^{-ix}=x- 2\pi  \left\lfloor \frac{x+\pi }{2 \pi }\right\rfloor$. This is the main place of hanging. But the true aproache is the second one.